# How should we answer questions that ask for scientific studies in the answer, but no studies have yet been conducted on the topic?

Tags: discussion

In this case, is it acceptable to cite a reputable blog or website, as well as some personal experience?

Comment: No. If there is no study that answers the question, the only possible answer is "There is not (yet) an answer."

Comment: @Flimzy seems like an answer to me.

Answer (score -1):

An answer saying "I tried using [academic paper search engine X] using terms A and B only came up with paper C which was talking about D and paper E talking about F" would be a good way of indicating that there may not be papers answering the question.